# Kendo UI kendoDropDownList dependent

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using Kendo UI inline editing and I had a **dropdownlist column** and a **value column**. But the value column are depending from the result in dropdownlist. [Here simple demo that I create](https://dojo.telerik.com/ADulOXUL/7)

For example:

1. if I select "Date", the value column use kendoDatePicker (yyyy/mm/dd)
2. if I select "Time", the value column use kendoTimePicker (24 hour format)
3. if I select "Amount", the value column use kendoNumericTextBox

I have update the demo and seem have a problem (*image below*) each time each time I change the value in dropdownlist?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in more details exactly what you are having problems with?

Comment: hi @Joe.. I had this function `valueTextField()` call from onchange event from my dropdownlist. When user choose a value from dropdownlist, textbox in column **value** will react from the based on dropdownlist value. For example, I choose "Date", and Value textbox should be in kendoDatePicker.

Comment: I have update the demo, now my issue each time I change the value in dropdownlist. Seem have a bug appear

Answer (score 0):

When switching the `SettingType` dropdown multiple times, you first need to remove the previous `Value` input before adding another one. The image provided indicates that both the `DatePicker` and the `TimePicker` are in the HTML at the same time.

Another approach would be to disable the `SettingType` dropdown after changing it so that you force the user to cancel their changes before making another selection.

```
function valueTextField() {
  var dropdownlist = $("#settingTypeName").data("kendoDropDownList");

  $('.k-dropdown').attr("disabled",true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
  ...
}
```